# how to get all products between two dates?

Tags: magento, magento-1.4

how to get all products between two dates like last month products, this month products , last week products and this week products etc.

i tried with this:

```
// current day to start with
$start = mktime(0,0,0,date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));;

// calculate the first day of last month
$first = date('YYYY-MM-DD',mktime(0,0,0,date('m',$start) - 1,1,date('Y',$start)));

// calculate the last day of last month
$last = date('YYYY-MM-DD',mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m') -1 + 1, 0, date('Y',$start)));



   if($filter == "lastmonth"){

    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', array('gteq' =>$first));
    $collection->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', array('lteq' => $last));


}
```

but i am not able to get the result :( any help ?

**Modified after Daniel response !**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I tried your code and had to swap `'lteq'` and `'gteq'` to make it work. The `$fromdate` is the lower number so you are searching for dates *greater than* that number.

Also you must remember to format the dates as MySQL likes it; `date('Y-m-d')`.

<sub>PS. See the [comparison operators](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-8-varien-data-collections) for a full list</sub>

Answer (score 17):

1) First of all you need to change you date formate from 'YYYY-MM-DD' to 'Y-m-d'. This will return a date formate which magento records have.

2) There is a special condition for date as bellow mention with your example.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', array('gteq' =>$first));
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', array('lteq' => $last));
```

To.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('updated_at', array(
        'from' => $first,
        'to' => $last,
        'date' => true,
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one issue with your code:

```
$collection->addFieldToFilter()
```

should be:

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter()
```

Answer (score 1):

I know that the question is little bit old but as it is quite well ranked in search engine results, I will correct the **date()** function that better take as arguments something like : **Y-m-d H:i:s**.
I hope it will help !